# Count number of character in a variable in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML which is describe below. This xml contains for example address node(**address1**). I just want to count the number of occurrence of character(**,**) in the address text. I am using template so just to mention I an storing address text into xslt variable.

Sample XML:

```
<xml>
    <address1>123 Fake Street, Alberta, Alberta, 234567</address1> 
    <address1>123 Fake Street, Alberta, Alberta</address1>
</xml>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="address" select="//*[local-name()='address1')]"/>
<xsl:variable name="totalComma" select="count(contains($address, ','))"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$totalComma = 3">
    <!--Do something-->
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$totalComma = 2">
    <!--Do something-->
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

I don't know whether this is correct solution or not but didn't get expected result. A little help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: xslt 1,0 or 2.0? With xslt 1.0 you can use a recursive template (or translate  if the possible character which are not',' are known (I would expect a no) )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `string-length(foo) - string-length(translate(foo, ',', ''))`.

Comment: Cool this will also do in 1.0

Comment: @Martin Thank you so much. Working as expected.